# find with regex not working as expected

Tags: linux, regex, find

I have a bunch of directories with numerical names, betwen 1 and 1,500 and I wanted to use the `find` command to find only these that are in range of 1,250 and 1,500, this regular expression should do that: `[1][2-5][0-9][0-9]` so Itried this command:

```
find . -regextype sed -regex "[1][2-5][0-9][0-9]"
```

But `find` finds nothing, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 1 find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) [emphasis mine]:

> `-regex pattern`
>   File name matches regular expression pattern. This is a match on **the whole path**, not a search. For example, to match a file named `./fubar3`, you can use the regular expression `.*bar.` or `.*b.*3`, but not `f.*r3`.

So this will find something:

```
find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/1[2-5][0-9][0-9]"
```

Note `[1][2-5][0-9][0-9]` you used covers the range 1200-1599. `[1]` can be just `1` as in my example.