# Find a file with parts of name in an arbitrary order

Tags: bash, find

I've got a file hidden somewhere, it's either named `file.foo.bar.txt` or `file.bar.foo.txt`, but I'm not sure which it is.

Right now, I'm just running `find file*foo*txt` because I know the file will be in the list, but I have to sort through the list to find the actual file.

Mostly out of curiosity (the list is short and realistically I can find the file), is there a way to `find file.(foo&bar).txt` such that the file will be found, regardless of which is the actual file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `find file*foo*txt` doesn't really use `find`.

It's your shell who expands `file*foo*txt` before `find` even runs. Then `find` gets possibly many arguments as its starting points; and no tests, no actions. The default action of `-print` is assumed.

This is like `printf '%s\n' file*foo*txt`. Both `printf` and your `find` only print what the shell supplies; except if there is no match. Or except if the shell returns a directory name (possibly among other names); in such case `printf` will just print it, while `find` will print it plus paths to every [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) in the directory, recursively.

Your task can be done with `find` (not the shell) actually performing some matching. Use several `-name` tests. The default behavior is to join tests with `-a` (logical AND). This fits cases where you want the filename to match several patterns at once.

```
find . -type f -name 'file.*' -name '*.txt' -name '*.foo.*' -name '*.bar.*'
```

Notes:

- These patterns are not regular expressions. `*` here is a wildcard but `.` is literal. I used `.` because you wrote "`file.foo.bar.txt` or `file.bar.foo.txt`".
- `find` is recursive. Use `-maxdepth 1` or (if your `find` doesn't support it) read this: [Limit POSIX `find` to specific depth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618).
- Note the patterns are quoted. This is to protect them from being expanded by the shell (compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690)).

If you want literally `file.foo.bar.txt` or `file.bar.foo.txt` then use `-o` (logical OR):

```
find . -type f \( -name file.foo.bar.txt -o -name file.bar.foo.txt \)
```

Note [you often need parentheses with `-o`](https://superuser.com/a/1387985/432690). Without them `-type f -name … -o -name …` would not do what we want.

And there is `-regex`. [It's a match on the whole path](https://superuser.com/a/1394626/432690) and [there are several flavors](https://superuser.com/a/1488800/432690).

Answer (score 0):

The default operation in `find` is *and*, so for a loose match you can just use

```
find .  -name 'file*foo*txt' -name 'file*bar*txt'
```

but for a rigid match you can resort to a regular expression:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/file\.(foo\.bar|bar\.foo)\.txt'
```

You need to remember the regex has to match the full path, hence the `.*/` at the beginning.